# Exporting data in CSV format on the same table in different columns

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I am writing a couple of result tables and exporting them in Excel format. Here's a quick sample of my code in R:

```
prob = attributes(.Last.value)
clas1=factor(kn1)

#Exporting clas1 into Excel format. The file contains a single column and 430 rows

filename = paste("results", kk, ".csv", sep="")
write.csv(clas1, filename)

#Exporting prob into Excel format. The file also contains a single column and 430 rows 

fileprobs = paste("probs", kk, ".csv", sep="")
write.csv (prob$prob, fileprobs)
```

Since both `prob` and `clas1` are linked, I'd like to export them in a single table of two columns and 430 rows instead of splitting them into two different files.

Is there a way to do this and having `"prob"` as a header of the column `prob` and `"class"` as a header of the column `clas1`? I'm using `colnames` like so:

```
write.csv (prob$prob, fileprobs,col.names =c("prob"))
```

But I'm having the following error message:

```
 Warning message:
In write.csv(clas1, filename, col.names = c("classes")) :
  attempt to set 'col.names' ignored
```

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have both columns in the correct order, as in

```
prob <- 1:10
clas1 <- letters[1:10]
```

then you can put them in the same dataframe and export the dataframe:

```
bothColumns <- data.frame(prob=prob, class=clas1)

write.csv(x=bothColumns, file="both columns.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```